# Insert progressDialog in a thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a thrad that calls a function that populates a list in an activity, I would put a progressDialog when the function is running, I wonder what I do to change the progress dialog is invoked when the activity is called, follows current code :

```
new Thread(){            
         public void run() {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {       
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        loadList();
                    }
                });
            }
         }.start();
```

Comment: Note that with this code sample the list loading actually occurs on the UI thread. This code therefore accomplishes nothing, because as soon as the thread is started (probably from the UI thread), execution is marshaled back directly to the UI thread.

Instead, you should load the relevant data on the newly created thread and then just *update the view* on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be better off using an AsyncTask, easy to attach a progress dialog to this.

Here's an example: http://droidapp.co.uk/?p=177

Comment: +1: Use an Asynctask for your background job because you can use the onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(), and onProgressUpdate() callbacks to update your UI on the UI thread.

Comment: I can make the progressdialog stay on screen for 3 seconds, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Create and start your progress dialog in the UI-Thread, then start your Thread. Create a Runnable object which dissmiss() your progress. Invoke this Runnable when you finished populating your list with runOnUiThread.